# How to find the object the mouse is hovering over VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms

I am making an application in VB.NET and would like to know if there is a way to get a pointer to the object the mouse is hovering over when the mouse click is released, essentially a drag-drop operation, however, I would much rather not have to use coordinates, since it would make my program very inefficient.

Comment: What kind of object do you want to find? Something located in a container control? Something located in one of your forms? Anything that is located on that part of the screen??

Comment: If it is `essentially a drag-drop operation` and you are using the DragDrop event, what does it matter what object you are over?

Comment: If you're using VB then talk of getting pointers to objects is meaningless. I suggest that you explain what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than how you're trying to achieve it. To do exactly what you asked, you could call `Bounds.Contains` on each control and pass the mouse coordinates as the `Point` to find. You'd need to loop through the controls by z-order from front to back.